# Secure app credentials against a specific domain it is not working for the maps.api.here

Tags: here-api

I have enabled the secure app credentials against a specific domain.  It is working fine for the reverse.geocoder.api.here and geocoder.api.here but not for the maps.api - the maps.api.here is acepting requests from domains not specified in the list. Is there any limitation for the maps.api.here?

Any help would be appreciated, will provide more information, if needed.

Comment: Please provide the api you are trying with and the domain you have provided.

Comment: I'm using the Map Tile API (https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/topics/quick-start-map-tile.html). The domain is walk-run-ride.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your secure app credentials against a specific domain are still valid and working. Map Tile API works in a specific design that it caches whenever it is queried and the cache is saved for considerable amount of time. Any requests made post the first query will be served from the Cache without considering the app_id and code. The team is working to modify the model but for now you need not worry since the requests served from Cache are not looking/counting your app id and code for a transaction. Hope this helps!